# Handling incrementing JSON name using Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, decode

I have a JSON object with incrementing names to parse and I want to store the output into an object with a name field and a list of pet field. I normally use JSONDecoder as its pretty handy and easy to use, but  I don't want to hard-code the CodingKey as I think it is very bad practice.

Input:

```
{"shopName":"KindHeartVet", "pet1":"dog","pet2":"hamster","pet3":"cat",  ...... "pet20":"dragon"}
```

The object that I want to store the result in is something like the following.

```
class VetShop: NSObject, Decodable {
var shopName: String?
var petList: [String]?

private enum VetKey: String, CodingKey {
    case shopName
    case petList
}

required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: VetKey.self)
    shopName = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .shopName)

    // implement storing of petList here.
}
```

}

What I'm struggling a lot on is, as CodingKey is enum, its a let constants, so I can't modify (and shouldn't modify) a constant, but I need to map the petList to the "petN" field, where N is the incrementing number.

**EDIT :**

I definitely cannot change the API response structure because it is a public API, not something I developed, I'm just trying to parse and get the value from this API, hope this clear the confusion!

Comment: @FaysalAhmed The api was badly written unfortunately, so I want to ask what will be the best practice to handle situation like api is returning you something funny.

Comment: So instead of using `Decodable` you can use Dictionary pattern to parse this JSON.

Comment: Are you using Almofire to get the response?

Comment: @FaysalAhmed Nah I basically use URLSession.shared.dataTask(url) to load out the data and process them using the decoder. How do you work this out with a dictionary pattern?

Comment: Why don't you make an api change?? You can ask for an array of pet

Comment: @Md.Sulayman can you explain it further? If my original query is search.php?s=KindHeartVet and it sends me a list of vet shop objects, how do I alter the query to have them send me a list of attributes with incrementing name without hardcoding things like pet1 pet15 etc?

Comment: @JimmyLow I mean your api response is not good or organized. As the api is providing some pet named pet1,pet2, It is better to send it in a array/list from api end. So that you won't have to think about incremented order.  You can contact your api provider if possible. As you are not sure how many Pet items will be in that api, you can't decode it with a fixed model as you number of property is not fixed in that case.

Comment: @JimmyLow But you can convert this json to dictionary, then check if your key contains prefix named pet then put it in a array.. By this way you can handle your problem in my opinion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Codable` has provisions for dynamic keys. If you absolutely can't change the structure of the JSON you're getting, you could implement a decoder for it like this:

```
struct VetShop: Decodable {
    let shopName: String
    let pets: [String]

    struct VetKeys: CodingKey {
        var stringValue: String
        var intValue: Int?
        init?(stringValue: String) {
            self.stringValue = stringValue
        }
        init?(intValue: Int) {
            self.stringValue = "\(intValue)";
            self.intValue = intValue
        }
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: VetKeys.self)
        var pets = [String]()
        var shopName = ""
        for key in container.allKeys {
            let str = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: key)
            if key.stringValue.hasPrefix("pet") {
                pets.append(str)
            } else {
                shopName = str
            }
        }
        self.shopName = shopName
        self.pets = pets
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to parse your data as `Dictionary`. In this way, you can get all keys of the dictionary.

```
    let url = URL(string: "YOUR_URL_HERE")
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
        do {
            let dics = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as! Dictionary<String, Any>
            let keys = [String](dics.keys)
            print(keys) // You have the key list
            print(dics[keys[0]]) // this will print the first value
         } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
    }).resume()
```

I hope you can figure out what you need to do.